# undefined method '+@' - Ruby Error

Tags: ruby, methods, undefined, nomethoderror

I have been trying to write a while loop in Ruby similar to the following:

```
number = 3
string = "lalaLand"
def main(number, string)
    n = 1
    while n <= number do
        print string + 'something else' + n.to_s
        n = n + 1
    end
end
main(number, string)
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
...: undefined method `+@' for "lalaLand":String (NoMethodError)
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

----EDIT--- (actual code, maybe there is something I missed)

`devel_number` is the only one declared as an int (ie: `devel_number = 4`, the rest are strings: `project_name = "lalaLand"`)
...

```
def b_sani_dev(project_home, source_dir, project_name, devel_number)

    n = 1
    while n <= devel_number do
        system 'mkdir -p ' + project_home + 'dev_'+ n.to_s + '/main'
        system 'mkdir -p ' + project_home + 'dev_' + n.to_s + '/LOG'
        n = n + 1
    end            
    b_sani_dev(project_home, source_dir, project_name, devel_number)
```

Comment: def b_sani_dev(project_home, source_dir, project_name, devel_number)
    n = 1
    while n <= devel_number do
        system 'mkdir -p ' + project_home + 'dev+'+ n.to_s + '/m'
        system 'mkdir -p ' + project_home + 'dev_' + n.to_s + '/L'
        n = n + 1
    end

Comment: hmm my bad, Will add edit for real code

Comment: Both your code examples work perfectly fine. They are horribly formatted, hideously complex, ugly, and totally un-idiomatic, but they *do* work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

All of the code you've posted should work fine but the error stems from attempting to use the unary `+` operator on a string, which is illegal.

```
+17   # totally fine
+"hi" # throws an error; what does this even mean?
```

Comment: Yes, when adding two strings, `+` will work. Your error message comes from attempting to use a `+` on just one string, which makes no sense.